# Crear un programa que le permita ver cuantos objetos se han creado de una clase

Tags: java, object

En esta ocasión quisiera saber cómo sería la manera más inteligente y limpia de crear un programa que diga *cuántos objetos se han creado en una clase*.

He tratado de hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
    /*Crear un programa que le permita ver cuantos objetos se han creado de una clase
```

public class ContadorObjetos{

```
static int contador;

public static void main(String[]args){

    ContadorObjetos obj1=new ContadorObjetos();
    ContadorObjetos obj2=new ContadorObjetos();

    System.out.println("Actualmente existen "+contador+"objetos en esta clase");
}
```

}

Pero efectivamente la variable contador me da *0*. He escuchado que se podría hacer con un Array... pero prefiero asegurarme y preguntar por aquí.

Agradezco sus respuestas claras y entendibles. Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crea una variable estática dentro de la clase que se incremente con cada nueva instancia:

```
public class miClase {
    private static int cantidad;
    public miClase() {
        cantidad++;
    }
    public static int getCantidad() {
        return cantidad;
    }
    protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
        cantidad--;
        super.finalize();
    }
}
```

Luego sólo tienes que aplicar el método `getCantidad`:

```
miClase clase1 = new miClase();
miClase clase2 = new miClase();

System.out.println ("Cantidad: " + miClase.getCantidad();
```

Comment: Hola _Oundroni_. Estoy aprendiendo, y el último método que utilizaste no lo entiendo muy bien. Podrías decirme si es necesario? y por qué? Gracias

Comment: @Brian sucede que el método `finalize` se llama cuando se va a liberar un objeto de memoria. Usualmente no debe sobre escribirse puesto que si falla no volverá a ejecutarse.

Comment: @BrianMartínez tal vez te sirva, es sobre el método finalize() http://programacion.net/articulo/tutorjava_nivel_basico_97/19

Comment: @Diego el artículo explica lo básico del método, pero no explica los riesgos que tiene sobre escribirlo. Aquí [una pregunta y respuestas](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/288715/102805) interesantes al respecto (en inglés).

Answer (score 1):

La opción más sencilla es aumentar el valor del contador en el constructor de la clase:

```
public class LaClase {
    static int contadorInstancias = 0;

    public LaClase() {
        contadorInstancias++;
        //resto de lógica del constructor
    }

    public static int getContadorInstancias() {
        return contadorInstancias;
    }
}
```

Si tienes múltiples constructores, entonces te recomiendo utilizar un bloque de inicialización que se ejecutará sin importar qué constructor sea invocado:

```
public class LaClase {
    static int contadorInstancias = 0;
    {
        contadorInstancias++;
    }
    public LaClase() {
        //código de constructor
    }
    public LaClase(String arg) {
        //código de constructor
    }

    public static int getContadorInstancias() {
        return contadorInstancias;
    }
}
```

Ahora, considera que esta alternativa sufre de un grave problema en ambientes concurrentes. Para este caso, sería mejor utilizar un `AtomicInteger` en lugar de una variable de tipo `int`:

```
public class LaClase {
    static AtomicInteger contadorInstancias = new AtomicInteger(0);

    public LaClase() {
        contadorInstancias.incrementAndGet();
        //código de constructor...
    }

    public static int getContadorInstancias() {
        return contadorInstancias.get();
    }
}
```